# Mirror a rotation transform

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, 3d, rotations, quaternions

In the process of making a game where I have "Rooms" where exits/entrances are marked by an invisible arrow on the rim. If I can get these parallel and facing opposite I'm golden.

Basically I want to snap these arrows together, but mirrored. So getting the translation (x,y,z) right is simple, I take Room A's arrow and just set Room B's to it.

But rotation is not as simple, I tried some naive approaches, such as (roll,pitch,yaw)*-1 and (roll-180,pitch-180,yaw-180) but these are incorrect. Especially if a point ends up at translation (0,0,0).

**[Crude image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NT3C.png)**

Not sure if quaternion math would help with anything but I am open to any reasonable approach. Sorry if my terminology is off it's been about 10 years since I took linear algebra which I barely passed anyway hoho.

So: for any rotation+translation of A, get the opposite rotation of B.

Comment: To clarify: Let's assume room A's connection point is at $\vec{c}_A$, with normal $\hat{n}_A$; and similarly for room B, $\vec{c}_B$ and $\hat{n}_B$. You wish to rotate room B so that $\hat{n}_A = -\hat{n}_B$, and then translate it so that the connection points coincide, right? Unfortunately, a single normal vector is not enough; the other room may be rotated around the normal. You need a second normal vector (always perpendicular to $\hat{n}$), perhaps a vector denoting which way is "up", say $\hat{u}_A$ and $\hat{u}_B$. Then, you can directly calculate the rotation matrix for room B.

Comment: To clarify, could the second normal needed be some default "world space up"? The game has gravity (in a global box-like way, not a spherical way) so there is a global up vector in that sense.

Comment: A global "world space up" works if you dont have any rooms that connect on top of each other, because then the normal vector and global up would then be parallel. Think of the connection points as a pin and a hole: they will join the rooms all right, but you need something else in addition to ensure they are not rotated in relation to each other. The second vector acts like an orientation key, making sure the two rooms are connected in a specific orientation, and not rotated around the pin.